# Hibernate Search - Disable _source

Tags: hibernate-search

I am using `Postgres` database and `Hibernate Search` (6.0.3) with `Elastic Search`(ES) backend. I want to store ***only the index*** in ES, by default Hibernate Search is also storing the data for the indexed fields (in `_source`).

How to create an index in Hibernate Search (for Elasticsearch backend) without the data (`_source`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** [Disabling the _source field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html#disable-source-field) from Hibernate Search configuration is possible starting with Hibernate Search 6.1.0.Beta1: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#_custom_index_mapping

---

Old answer for Hibernate Search 6.0 only:

If you mean [disabling the _source field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html#disable-source-field), there is no built-in feature for that in Hibernate Search at the moment.

You could [disable automatic index creation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-schema-management-strategy) and create the indexes and their mappings yourself, with `mappings._source` set to `false`, but that would be unpleasant as that would require listing every single field in your index.

It should be possible to add a setting in Hibernate Search itself to disable the source in the indexes it creates, much like the [existing setting to mark the mapping as dynamic](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-elasticsearch-mapping-dynamic). It probably won't be too hard since Hibernate Search itself doesn't rely directly on the source (except for projections, but you may not need them).

I encourage you to [open a ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH) if you want such a setting.

Comment: After the index creation request is built, is there a way to just add `"_source": {       "enabled": false     } `

Comment: Normally you would include that in the index creation request, but you could try an [mapping update request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) with a body containing only `{"_source": {       "enabled": false     }}`. Supposedly it will get merged with the existing mapping. Some properties cannot be changed after index creation, though, and I don't know if `_source` is one of them. You will have to try.

Comment: The mapping update is not allowed, I tried it. Is there any other way in code? `1.` intercept the index creation PUT and add `_source` json to the body or  `2` probably somehow add the `_source` json to `AbstractTypeMapping.extraAttributes` ? How can I include it in the creation request?

Comment: No, I don't think there is a way to intercept index creation requests within Hibernate Search. Really, the best way to handle this would be to open a ticket, and maybe to send a pull request. If the PR is good I can get the patch released in a week. Implementation-wise, it would be very similar to [the `dynamic_mapping` setting](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-elasticsearch-mapping-dynamic]. Later, we can think of a more general approach, similar to https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/pull/2438 but for the mapping.

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4234

Comment: @Nikhil I assume you need that for your [massive dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68468049/6692043)? We plan to work on https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-4253 in the next few sprints, so you will likely be able to configure this in the 6.1.0.Alpha1 release, which if all goes well will happen in a few weeks (I need to wrap up a few other things).

Comment: @Nikhil Disabling `_source` is now possible in Hibernate Search 6.1.0.Beta1: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#_custom_index_mapping